# Dynamic images and formatting parameters with @Ajax.ActionLink

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I’m trying to change the following working code into Ajax.

```
   <a href="@Url.Action("Index", new { pn = pc })"> 
   <img src="@Url.Content("~/Photos/" + @photoFile[pc])", id = "imgnb" width = "100px" height = "150px" alt = "Photo" /></a>  <br />
```

The code needs to handle a string[] variable, @photoFile[pc]), and take  formatting, ( id = "imgnb" width = "100px" height = "150px" alt = "Photo").  (imgnb is css, no image border)

Soe Moe built an Ajax helper here [Problem with ajax.actionlink helper, return string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5165948/problem-with-ajax-actionlink-helper-return-string).

His code works great with a static image with no paratmeters.

```
         @Ajax.ImageActionLink("../../Photos/Children/albersona1.jpg", "Index", new { pn = pc }, new AjaxOptions
    {
      UpdateTargetId = "Selected Thumbnail",
      InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace,
      HttpMethod = "GET" })
```

Would anyone know how to modify this helper to convert the URL.Action into Ajax so that it handles dynamic images and formatting parameters.

Any help greatly appreciated.

Thanks, Joe

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
public static class ImageActionLinkHelper
{
    public static IHtmlString ImageActionLink(
        this AjaxHelper helper,
        string imageUrl,
        string actionName,
        object routeValues,
        object htmlAttributes,
        AjaxOptions ajaxOptions
    )
    {
        var builder = new TagBuilder("img");
        builder.MergeAttribute("src", imageUrl);
        builder.MergeAttributes(new RouteValueDictionary(htmlAttributes));
        var link = helper.ActionLink("[replaceme]", actionName, routeValues, ajaxOptions);
        var html = link.ToHtmlString().Replace("[replaceme]", builder.ToString(TagRenderMode.SelfClosing));
        return new HtmlString(html);
    }
}
```

and then:

```
@Ajax.ImageActionLink(
    Url.Content("~/Photos/" + photoFile[pc]),
    "Index",
    new { pn = pc },
    new { id = "imgnb", width = "100px", height = "150px", alt = "Photo" },
    new AjaxOptions
    {
        UpdateTargetId = "foo"
    }
)
```

Comment: As usual right on the mark Darin, it works great.  I added two lines to your code in the AjaxOptions:                "InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace, HttpMethod = "GET".                                           Thanks, Joe

Comment: For others FYI you need to add a "using System.Web.Routing;" to your extension .cs file along with the following two that were already there.  using System.Web.Mvc;  using System.Web.Mvc.Ajax;